# Covariance problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

The experiment is a three hat experiment with the following probabilities: $\frac15$ for $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$ and $(3,2,1)$, and $\frac1{10}$ probability for $(2,3,1)$ and $(3,1,2)$. Find $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, N)$ where $X_1$ is person $1$ getting their hats so $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$. $N$ is the # of people who get their own hats back.

Okay I did the following:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, N)=E(X_1N)-E(X_1)E(N)$$

$$E(X_1)=1\left(\frac15\right) + 1\left(\frac15\right) + 1\left(\frac15\right)=.6$$

$$E(N)=1\left(\frac15\right) + 1\left(\frac15\right) + 1\left(\frac15\right) + 3\left(\frac15\right) + 0\left(\frac1{10}\right)\color{red}{+}0\left(\frac1{10}\right)=1.2$$
$$E(X_1N)=E[(X_1-E(X_1))(N-E(N))]$$
$$E(X_1N)= (1-.6)(1-1.2)+(1-.6)(1-1.2)+(1-.6)(1-1.2)=-.24?$$

$-.24 - (.6\times 1.2)=-.96$ wrong

The correct answer is $\frac8{25}$

help? Where did i go wrong exactly? I think i went about it wrong in calculating $E(X_1N)$ but i'm not sure.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a very recent question (possibly by the same user)?

Comment: where? I asked something similar regarding this experiment(how to calculate the expected value) but not the covariance. Could you help me though? : (

Comment: Hi @bobthebuilder! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now but you might like to know that we use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here. Can you do it? Yes you can! :)

Comment: Hey Shaun, thanks i always wondered how that is done. I'll look into it for next questions. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: You're welcome $\ddot\smile$

Comment: "where?" Surely you know very well "where", so why do you ask?

Comment: No i don't, because i have no clue if you and i are talking about the same thing. You said i asked the same question which i most certainly did not. I asked about this experiment and the question was regarding finding the expected value of N and its variance. The question was not about finding the Covarience using X1 and N. If you are not going to be helpful then stop commenting.

Comment: *Master always so nice...* Say, which question was this previous one? Did you delete it? (Unrelated: what about using @...)

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$E[X_k]=\frac25,\qquad E[X_kX_\ell]=\frac15,\qquad N=\sum_{k=1}^3X_k,
$$
hence
$$
E[X_kN]=\frac25+\frac15+\frac15=\frac45,\qquad E[N]=3\cdot\frac25=\frac65,$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X_k,N)=\frac45-\frac25\cdot\frac65=\frac8{25}.
$$